# How can i fix json search

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio

I have an android program that reads the existing text and converts it into text
The program searches the text via the json link

ِAt first the calling function

```
new JsonTask().execute("https://api.myjson.com/bins/gx1ck");
```

My code of [Class JsonTask](https://textuploader.com/1srug)

But my problem is that the program stops working at the beginning of the search link

Comment: Please share some more details: does it crash, or freeze? What's the LogCat output?

Comment: I can't catch the LogCat, they still moving up